# Scene lighting and setup: how would you get such a render?

Tags: light, shaders, shadows

Just for fun, i'm trying to recreate a scene from the (nice) movie Cherry 2000.  Here's [a link to the clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKEU7z2ac78).

[image]

I like the aesthetic, but I can't figure out how they did setup their scene; and that's what I would like to understand.
Would it be possible to recreate something similar with Blender ?

There is a woman, a red spot, and... a metallic curtain ? Is this a metallic curtain for the shadows to be distorted like this ?

- How did they do to have the shadow so sharpened ?
- Where is placed the lady compared to the camera ?  And is she behind the curtain ?  Then it couldn't be a metallic curtain ?
- How did they lighten the scene ? The more "metallic" my curtain is, the more narrow the light "slice" I get.

Well, i'm sure I could learn more things about materials and lighting by understanding this.

Your input is welcome! I have nothing convincing yet but I can share my actual file so you can play with the curtain : [the file is here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7xr4dtkww5o915s/store-cherry2000-4.blend?dl=0).

[image]

And here's a test with Suzanne between the camera and the curtain - but that's cheating; I did hide the object from cycles so i get only its shadow (Ray Visibility)

[image]

Comment: Nothing wrong with cheating if you get the result you want.

Comment: Yes, but in this case, I should not need to cheat.  There must be a way to recreate the same setup....